# pentaho variable same name job and transformation

Tags: pentaho

I have a variable in the job called week_start and I also have a variable in a transformation inside this job also called week_start.
My question is, if I put week_start in the job equal to 202021 and put week_start equal to 202030 in the job, which value the transformation will use when I execute from the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set any variable in the transformation you can not be used those variables in that transformation. Because all steps in a transformation run in parallel without a certain order of execution.

So, the rule is- you can set the variables you want to use in the first transformation of JOB.

Note:- If you set variables inside transformation, you can use those variables from job.

I have prepare a sample transformation & job for you [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pmA4d_nWKVcqBJE_aKaBEXCSJM_f9K6Z?usp=sharing). You can get full idea from log after run the job where I have set 2 variables with same name 'week_start' in both transformation and job.

In short, if i want to give your answer then that will be "when you execute the job then value you use for job -will be/need to be use inside transformation"